# How to apply regex on {} parameter in Linux in find command

Tags: regex, linux, find, command, exec

I want to change the file name on a certain type of files. It should run recursively. 
I have almost got it and don't know how to work with the parameter {} (the absolute Path).

```
      find $PWD -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec echo " {} " \;
```

For example, I want to change the extensions using reg. expressions and not the command rename etc. I need sometimes new name to pass it to a function, therefore rename is not applicable here.It should be possible to work with the parameter like in for-case with the parameter $each:

```
      for each in /* do echo "${each\./\}.png" done
```

How can I apply regex on parameter {}, like here: "${each \ . / \ }.png"?

Comment: I've looked into your problem, and I encountered some weird issues. I've tried something like `find $PWD -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec basename {} .jpg \;`, and it returns the name of the file without the extension. However, when I try `find $PWD -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec echo $(basename {} .jpg).png \;` , it works as if I had written `echo {}.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround of the `basename` misbehaving when using it with `find` :

```
find $PWD -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename "$0" .jpg).png"' {} \;
```

`sh` forces the following commands to be interpretated using your `/bin/sh` file. The `-c` option specifies arguments are passed as strings (here, your argument `$0` is `{}`).

If you have the following files :

```
/home/username/image1.jpg
/home/username/Documents/image2.jpg
```

This will output :

```
image1.png
image2.png
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the full path, you can use this :

```
find $PWD -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'echo "${0%%.jpg}".png' {} \;
```

This will output :

```
/home/username/image1.png
/home/username/Documents/image2.png
```

Comment: This possibility as well the above one helped me!Thanks:)

Comment: @user3328286 glad I could help :) I this answer was usefull, don't forget to accept it so that it closes your question

Comment: do you mean to vote up? I would like, but I cannot yet. only 5 reputation:)

Comment: @Alexito no, there is a cross next to the vote up/down button. Click it to accpet the answer